# Neo4j verbose output reason

Tags: neo4j

I'm wondering why there is so much repetition in the output that neo4j returns. As an example for the following query/graph:

```
MATCH p=()-[r:ACTED_IN]->() RETURN p LIMIT 2
```

[image]

This returns two results in the form of `(Person, Relationship, Movie)`:

```
{
  "start": {
"identity": 1,
"labels": [
      "Person"
    ],
"properties": {
"name": "Keanu Reeves",
"born": 1964
    }
  },
  "end": {
"identity": 87,
"labels": [
      "Movie"
    ],
"properties": {
"tagline": "Pain heals, Chicks dig scars... Glory lasts forever",
"title": "The Replacements",
"released": 2000
    }
  },
  "segments": [
    {
      "start": {
"identity": 1,
"labels": [
          "Person"
        ],
"properties": {
"name": "Keanu Reeves",
"born": 1964
        }
      },
      "relationship": {
"identity": 114,
"start": 1,
"end": 87,
"type": "ACTED_IN",
"properties": {
"roles": [
            "Shane Falco"
          ]
        }
      },
      "end": {
"identity": 87,
"labels": [
          "Movie"
        ],
"properties": {
"tagline": "Pain heals, Chicks dig scars... Glory lasts forever",
"title": "The Replacements",
"released": 2000
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "length": 1.0
}
```

But this seems quite verbose, and I can't figure out why it wouldn't just return something like this:

```
{
    "start": {"identity": 1, "labels": ["Person"], "properties": {"name": "Keanu Reeves", ...}},
    "edge": {"identity": 11, "start": 1, "end": 7, "type": "ACTED_IN",  "properties" {...}},
    "end": {"identity": 7, "labels": ["Movie"], "properties": {"name" "The Replacements", ...}}
}
```

Or am I missing a lot of things in my conception of what needs to be rendered in the result-set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A path can be longer than one hop, and can contain more than two nodes and more than one relationship. So your format won't work in the general case.

However, the format you propose is the one used in the `segments` key. Each segment has `start`, `relationship`and `end`.